# Writing data to CSV file that updates on an interval and indexes to a new row upon each new day

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi3

I'm collecting run-time data on machines for OEE using a RPi3B+. My program uses RPi.GPIO threaded callbacks and sensors to detect the status of certain stations. I have counters keeping track of good/bad parts, parts in, and a timer that counts downtime when none of the sensors are triggered after a set time.

Currently, my outputs (OEE, yield, run-time, etc.) are all calculated based on the counters/timers upon either:

1) a new day

2) a keyboard interrupt.

I plan to add the output calculation during an interval that is looped in my code (let's say every minute or so).

What I want is to write the current values of my output variables to a single row in a CSV file and update/overwrite that same row (about every minute).

I also want to add some code to my "new day" loop that will index to the next row and start continuously updating that row's column variables once a new day occurs.

In the end, it would continuously update the variables in the current day's row and upon a new day, leave the state of the prior row and move onto the next row to be continuously updated until the following day- and so on.

I'm fairly new to python and I'm having trouble with filewriting, reading etc. Any help is appreciated on how to get started on this type of problem.